# variable sized int matrix in ARM assembler

Tags: c, assembly, matrix, int, arm

I am currently trying to implement a matrix multiplication in ARM assembler. I already read some tutorials about matrix calculations in assembler and they all use the NEON instructions on a 3x3 or 4x4 float matrix. But that's totally different to what i want to do. I have two symmetrical int matrices, so row and column number of both matrices are the same and my assembler function gets the size of the matrices as parameter, so i cant write a matMul function for just 3x3 or 4x4 matrices like in the tutorials.

So my question is what is the best and easiest way to do that? Is it even possible to use the NEON instructions with a 100x100 or even bigger matrix? And also the single- and double-precision registers are unnecessary, because i only have int numbers.

Another problem is, that I'm almost totally new to ARM assembler and so i don't understand the NEON instructions completely.

Comment: You should take a look at some of the tutorials linked on this blog post.  http://cv4mar.blogspot.com/2011/06/arm-neon-basic-tutorials.html    They appear to help some with NEON instructions a bit.  I would take some time to understand NEON a bit more completely and it should help your find your answer.

Comment: You'd also multiply large matrices by recursively working on smaller (e.g. 4x4) blocks. I don't know a good link to an implementation explanation off-hand, but [studying some of the general algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication) would be a start.

Comment: OK, that sounds already too complicated for the beginning, so i will start with the naive implementation and use 3 loops. Is there a way to allocate memory in assembler? or should i allocate it in the c code and give the assembler function 3 parameter, 2 pointer for the matrices to multiply and 1 pointer for the result matrix?

Comment: You can use **NEON**, but SIMD are generally optimized for 3x3 or 4x4 matrices.  Ie, the 'multiple data' part handles 3 or 4 values at a time (nice for graphics, etc).  To use *SIMD* with larger matrixes, you need to sub-divide it into smaller 4x4 operations/sub-matrixes.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but i can't really imagine how that should work with dividing the matrix into smaller ones. Does anyone have a description or some infos about that method?

Answer (score 0):

MAIN    PROC NEAR

```
  MOV DI,OFFSET M_RESULT
  MOV SI,OFFSET M_A
  MOV BX,OFFSET M_B
```

BACK1:
      MOV CH,N
      SUB CH,LINE 
      MOV COLUMN,N

BACK2:

```
  MOV AL,CH  
  MOV X,N
  MUL X
  ADD SI,AX
  MOV AH,0
  MOV AL,P
  ADD BX,AX
  MOV COUNTER,N 
  MOV TEMP,0

BACK3:
  MOV AL,[SI]
  MUL [BX] 
  ADD TEMP,AX
  INC SI
  ADD BX,N
DEC COUNTER
JNZ BACK3


  MOV AX,TEMP
  MOV [DI],AX
  ADD DI,2    
  MOV SI,OFFSET M_A 
  MOV BX,OFFSET M_B 
  INC P
```

DEC COLUMN
   JNZ BACK2

```
  MOV P,0
```

DEC LINE
  JNZ BACK1

```
;
MOV AX,4C00H   ;8- End of 
INT 21H        ;9- processing
```

MAIN    ENDP           ; End of procedure
CODESG  ENDS           ; End of segment
    END START      ; End of program
;By : Mojtaba Alizadeh
    INT 21H        ;9- processing
MAIN    ENDP           ; End of procedure
CODESG  ENDS           ; End of segment
    END START